# Trouble when trying to rotate (in 3d) two elements at the same time in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make these card game and there is a function that when I click on the player card it is suposse that both cards flip (the pc and tha player card), after that I will compare them. For that I add a class called flip, which rotates them 180deg (in CSS). The question is that it does not work, since when clicking only the one that was clicked is turned, not the other. This is the code (the suits are in spanish):

```js
const value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
const suit = ['pick', 'corazon', 'trebol', 'carro'];



function createDeck(suit, value, numberPlayer) {
  let arrayCards = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {

      let c = new Card(value[i], suit[j], numberPlayer)

      arrayCards.push(c);
    }
  }
  return arrayCards;
}


class Card {
  constructor(value, suit, numberPlayer) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.numberPlayer = numberPlayer;
  }
}


class Deck extends Card {
  constructor(deck, numberPlayer) {
    super(value, suit, numberPlayer);
    this.deck = deck;
    this.numberPlayer = numberPlayer;
  }

  shuffle() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.deck.length));
      var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.deck.length));
      var tmp = this.deck[location1];

      this.deck[location1] = this.deck[location2];
      this.deck[location2] = tmp;
    }
    return this;
  }

  htmlCards() {

    let elementParent = document.querySelector('div[data-player="' + this.numberPlayer + '"]');
    let deck = document.createElement('div');
    deck.classList.add('deck');
    elementParent.appendChild(deck);
    this.deck.forEach(card => {

      deck.innerHTML += `<div class="card" data-player="` + this.numberPlayer + `" data-value="` + card.value + `">
                                 <div class="front"></div>
                                 <div class="back">
                                 <div class="value">${card.value == 1 ? 'A' : ''}${card.value == 11 ? 'J' : ''}${card.value == 12 ? 'Q' : ''}${card.value == 13 ? 'K' : ''}${card.value < 10 ? card.value : ''}</div>
                                 <div class="suit ${card.suit}"></div>
                                 </div>`

    });

  }
}

//we shuffle the cards and we create the html cards...
let mazoPlayer = new Deck(createDeck(suit, value, 1), 1)
mazoPlayer.shuffle();
mazoPlayer.htmlCards();

let mazoPc = new Deck(createDeck(suit, value, 2), 2)
mazoPc.shuffle();
mazoPc.htmlCards();

//Now we create the game...


let playerCard = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-player="1"][data-value]'));
let pcCard = document.querySelectorAll('[data-player="2"][data-value]');
let playing = false;



function play() {
  let playing = true;
  this.classList.add('flip');
  pcCard[0].classList.add('flip');
}



playerCard.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', play))
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pc" data-player="2"></div>

  <div class="player" data-player="1"></div>
</body>
```

I don't know if it's due to overlapping events, or something like that, since when I replace "For Each" with the pcCard, the reaction is similar but the other way around: the other card flips.